# How to add custom section in WooCommerce Products settings page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I am trying to add a dynamic field on **`WooCommerce -> Settings -> Products -> My Settings`** page

I follow this tutorial but its does not help in what I want to achieve.

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/adding-a-section-to-a-settings-tab/

I want to achieve something like this.

[image: My Custom Setting interface]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because I have the time, I have created you an example...

you can find it here: 
[woocommerce-woorei-dynamic-section-fields.php](https://github.com/reigelgallarde/woocommerce-test-folder/blob/master/woocommerce-woorei-dynamic-section-fields.php)

just upload it on your plugins folder then activate to test.
You can edit it for your needs.

for reference or to give you a hint, you can look for this files.

in my plugin line 58, take note of the `type` and `id`. actually `id` here can be anything other than empty string.

```
$settings_slider[] = array( 
   'type' => 'woorei_dynamic_field_table', 
   'id' => 'woorei_dynamic_field_table' 
);
```

take note also on the functions that comes next to it. Look at the names to get the idea.

then at woocommerce folder, take a look at this.

`woocommerce\includes\admin\class-wc-admin-settings.php` line 618
`woocommerce\includes\admin\class-wc-admin-settings.php` line 712

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  Can we create interface exactly how it is shown in my screenshot? This is because I want to match it with other fields. Current is looking a bit OFF because other fields shows Label at left and Field on right. Please update the code.

Comment: I inspected the code using firebug and I see the actual table is empty and custom table is injected beneath it. 

<table class="form-table"> </table>
<table class="woorei_mysettings wc_input_table sortable widefat"> ....

Comment: I think  <table class="form-table"> </table> shouldn't be empty. It should have a <th> and a <td>, th for field label and td should contain the custom table, please have a look.

Comment: no, copy how the way my code is done if you already have one.. don't activate my plugin.... copy it and change the name and id of the inputs to correspond to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I am accepting the answer.